# How do I loop through documents in MongoDB using Python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a mongoDB database having many documents. Its structure is:

```
  "Tenant_Details": {
  "$Tenant_Name": {
    "Tenant Name" : "$Tenant_Name",
    "Tenant Address" : "$Tenant Address",
    "Tenant Contact" : "$ Tenant number",
    "System_ID" : "$System_ID",
    "$System_ID": [
      "List of assigned device numbers for $System_ID"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here **$** sign indicates the variable data.
But I am confused about looping through the **Tenant Details** for getting the "List of assigned device numbers". I won't be knowing the Tenant_Name, so I need to look at all documents of Tenant details matching the device numbers for System_ID.

How do I loop without knowing the Tenant_Name?

**EDIT1**:
I tried by storing the list of the Tenant Names in the DB and by looping through the list it worked. I tried like this:

```
TenantNames = db.find_one() # list of tenant Names
TenantDetailsObj = db.find_one()
SystemID = 1
deviceNumber = 2
for names in TenantNames:
   if deviceNumber in TenantDetailsObj.get(name).get(str(SystemID)):
           GotData = 1
```

But in this the Tenant name was known hence looping was easy, but I am not getting without knowing Tenant Name how do I loop?

Comment: A question on SO can not replace taking the time to get familiar with a topic, tool or library on your own. Please show us what you have tried or research so far!

Comment: @KlausD. I have updated the question please check once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops). Tentatively not "dupehammering" myself just yet. But this is what the question looks like.

Comment: This document doesn't seem right. Why not have the following instead:

 `{
     "Tenant_Name":  "abc",
     "Tenant Address" : "$Tenant Address",
     "Tenant Contact" : "$ Tenant number",
     "System_ID" : "$System_ID",
     "$System_ID": [
       "List of assigned device numbers for $System_ID"
     ]
 }`